# clear uploaded local object function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/QC76K/

```
  // Closure to capture the file information.
  reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
    return function(e) {
      // Render thumbnail.
      var span = document.createElement('span');
      span.innerHTML = ['<img class="thumb" src="', e.target.result,
                        '" title="', escape(theFile.name), '"/>'].join('');
      document.getElementById('list' + filesId).insertBefore(span, null);
    };
  })(f);
```

I want to add a 'clear all' button to this script. I use html("") to empty the note. I can't re-upload the photo still. where does it store? and how to clear that?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by - 'I can't re-upload the photo still'. Is there any check to see if the photo is already there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/QC76K/2/

```
// Add Clear Button in HTML Section
<button id="clear">Clearall</button>

document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', clearall, false);

function clearall(){
    var list = document.getElementById('list');
    var files = document.getElementById('files');

    list.innerHTML = "";
    files.value = "";
}
```

Comment: remove the entire list? I can't do that because my list is markup html which represent vary item like list1, list2 etc

Answer (score 0):

Just add this

```
function clearAll() {
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML='';
    document.getElementById('files').value=''; 
}
```

Working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sajith/Tk4XE/1/